# PostgreSQL: How to add a column in every table of a database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database with 169 tables

I need this column in every table:

```
wid integer not null primary key
```

I tried this(Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn for the solution):

```
SELECT 
  'ALTER TABLE ' + T.name + ' ADD foo int NULL'
FROM
  sys.tables AS T
WHERE
  T.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

But it didn't work on PostgreSQL.

It only worked on tsql.

How to add this column in every table at once ?

Comment: But I want to add a column in 169 tables at once.

Comment: so you want to add column `wid` in each and every _tables_ in your database ???

Comment: Yes Sir. I don't wanna do this by hand  :)

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. It's tsql.

Comment: @Kumar The link you provided is not related to OP question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
do $$
declare
    selectrow record;
begin
for selectrow in
    select 
      'ALTER TABLE '|| T.mytable || ' ADD COLUMN foo integer NULL' as script 
   from 
      ( 
        select tablename as mytable from  pg_tables where schemaname  ='public' --your schema name here
      ) t
loop
execute selectrow.script;
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

---

You can test whether all your *tables* altered with the new *column* using the following *select*

```
select 
     table_name,COLUMN_NAME
 from 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
 where 
   COLUMN_NAME='foo' -- column name here
```

Comment: Its absolutely wrong Winged. Your logic is incorrect in this case.

Comment: @ajay state your reason

Comment: As mentioned you have used wrong looping condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name still i dont think it will work in this case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i've tested this in my db all tables altered with new column `foo`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if possible test this in your environment

Comment: @GabrielLidenor see my latest EDIT

Comment: Sorry, the missing indention kind of tricked me. The execute is indeed inside the loop. You should be using `pg_tables` instead of `pg_stat_user_tables` in the first script though.

Comment: @Insider sounds like an issue related to your environment. Try with limit `where 
   COLUMN_NAME='foo' limit 2`

Answer (score 5):

Try this (change 'public' to whatever schema you're doing this in)

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    row record; 
    cmd text;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT schemaname, tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' LOOP
        cmd := format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD COLUMN foo SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ', row.schemaname, row.tablename);
        RAISE NOTICE '%', cmd;
        -- EXECUTE cmd;
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you run as is, it'll show you the commands. Uncomment the EXECUTE line to actually perform the alterations.

I'd run within a transaction so you can roll back if you're not happy with the results.

Note that the type is `SERIAL` - the column type will be integer, but also creates a sequence owned by the table and defaults the column value to the next value of that sequence.

Answer (score 2):

We may need to **check column is already exist or not**.

*Tested on PostgreSQL V10*

```
do $$
declare selectrow record;
begin
for selectrow in
    select 'ALTER TABLE '|| T.mytable || ' ADD COLUMN x_is_exported boolean DEFAULT FALSE' as script 
   from (select tablename as mytable from  pg_tables where schemaname  ='public') t
loop
    begin
        execute selectrow.script;
        EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_column THEN CONTINUE;
    END;
end loop;
end;
$$;
```